# How i can protect admin route from users in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have created a route which only admin can access that route on the basis of the user role that I'm getting from the typescript node backend in back end DB I have set admin role 1 for admin and 0 for user I also protect my route from backend which only admin can access it and its working well but I'm not able to do on my frontend how I can protect admin route using authguard in my frontend app Please anyone can Help Me Thanks In Advance.

This is my backend code for protecting route(APIs).

```js
export const authAdmin: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userInfo: any = await user.findOne(req.userId);
    console.log('User INfo Role ===', userInfo.role);
    if (userInfo.role === 0) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Un Authorized        Admin Access Denied' });
    next(); // next if admin role is 1
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: err,
    });
  }
};
```

This is my method to get user profile where user role is also coming

```js
export const getProfile: RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {
  const profile = await user.findOne({ _id: req.userId }).select('-password');
  return res.json(profile);
};
```

This is my if condition to hide route from user if not admin in html file

```html
<span class="ml-4">
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="afterMenu" *ngIf="userrole==1">
    Admin
  </button>
  <mat-menu #afterMenu="matMenu" xPosition="after">
    <button
      mat-menu-item
      [routerLink]="['/add-docotor']"
      routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
    >
      Add Doctor
    </button>
    <button
      mat-menu-item
      [routerLink]="['/manage-doctors']"
      routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
    >
      Manage Doctor
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
</span>
```

This is my jsonwebtoken verifying method where i'm getting userId from payload

```
  import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
  import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
  import { JWT_KEY } from "../config";

  interface IPayload{
    userId: string,
    iat:number,
    exp: number
  }

  export const userVerify  = (req:Request, res:Response, 
     next:NextFunction) => {
     let token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1] ;
     if(token){
        const payload = jwt.verify(token, JWT_KEY) as IPayload;
        if(!payload){
           return res.status(401).json({message: 'Un Authorized 
              User'});
        }else{
           req.userId = payload.userId;
           //console.log('Payload User ID ===', req.userId);
           //console.log('Whole Payload ===', payload);
           next();
        }
        }
      else{
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Un Authorized User .'
        });
      }
     }
```

```js
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { JWT_KEY } from '../config';
import user from '../models/user';
interface IPayload {
  userId: string;
  iat: number;
  exp: number;
}
export const userVerify = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  let token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
  if (token) {
    const payload = jwt.verify(token, JWT_KEY) as IPayload;
    if (!payload) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Un Authorized User' });
    } else {
      req.userId = payload.userId;
      console.log('Payload User ID ===', req.userId);
      console.log('Whole Payload ===', payload);
      next();
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: 'Un Authorized User .',
    });
  }
};
```

This is my service where i'm getting user profile

```js
getUserProfile(){
  return this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/doctors/profile')
}
```

I'm new in angular and i not know how i can use getUserProfile in my authGuard To Protect the route Please anyone can solve my issue

Comment: You should have a look at route guards i guess.

Comment: can you provide me reference or code ??

Comment: To learn about Angular-Routing-Guards, look at thus article: [Understanding Angular Guards](https://codeburst.io/understanding-angular-guards-347b452e1892?gi=2e44a5a883de)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CanActivate to protect Your Route from the Unauthuorized access for
the other Pages.

```html
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router:Router){

    }

    canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot,router:RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree |Promise<boolean | UrlTree> |Observable<boolean | UrlTree> 
    {

       
    }
}
```